# Strange operator with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, operators

I was reading some code and came across this thing. I don't have the whole context now save this line.

```
cout<<(*--*++ptr+1)<< endl;
```

this compiles fine and works when we input values in it..

its declaration is like this.

```
char ***ptr ;
```

What is this operator and is it included in the standard?

Comment: the answers suffice. these types of tricks are okay, i guess, but should be preceded with a comment stating what the operation intends to do and perhaps a brief explanation.

Comment: Is this real, production code?

Comment: it is real code in some programming puzzle.
i am a beginner, how can i just produce it myself.

Comment: Please provide the full code. How is ptr initialized?

Comment: You should stay away from [Three Star Programmers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) at all costs!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a single operator, it's a combination of several unary operators.  It gets parsed like this:

```
*(--(*(++ptr))) + 1
```

So, `ptr1` is first incremented, then dereferenced, then that value is decremented and dereferenced again.

Comment: The parentheses make it *much* easier to understand.  *[hint, if you're writing code similar to this]*

Comment: so is it equivalent to *ptr + 1?

Comment: @Ralph No, you're not decrementing at the same level of `*`s as you're incrementing.

Comment: @Ralph: No, it's not at all equivalent to that.  It is equivalent to first doing `++ptr; --(*ptr);` followed by evaluating `**ptr + 1`.